# Trying to find an hobby with the min average age

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that return the name of the Hobby with the minimal average of ages of the persons with that hobby.

I can get the minimal average of the ages hobby, but i cant get the Name attribute of the hobby himself.
This is how I'm getting the minimal age:

```
SELECT MIN(avg) 
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(age) as avg
    FROM Hobby H NATURAL JOIN Person P NATURAL JOIN Hobbies R
    GROUP BY (R.hnum))
```

The tables are :

```
Hobby (hnum, hname)
Person (pid, pname, age)
Hobbies (pid, hnum, frequency)
```

usually i would want to make this block an inner block and then compare between each hobby the min age but because hobby has no min age attribute i cant do it in this way.

I've updated a bit what Ersin Gülbahar suggested to this:

```
SELECT MIN(avg), name
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(age) as avg, min(hname)  name
    FROM Hobby H NATURAL JOIN Person P NATURAL JOIN Hobbies R
    GROUP BY (R.hnum))
```

But the only problem is that if there are two hobbies with the same minimal avg age this query return only one row.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

`SELECT MIN(avg), min(name) 
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(age) as avg, min(hname)  name
    FROM Hobby H NATURAL JOIN Person P NATURAL JOIN Hobbies R
    GROUP BY (R.hnum))`

Comment: thank you. I just need to understand what will happen if i want in the end to get only the hobby's name, i'll have to get rid of the MIN(abg) in the first SELECT section right ?, why this still this give me the minimal of the ages ? because you did 2 aggregate operation in the inner and the min(name)work after the min(age) ?

Comment: Instead of your first line i wrote 'SELECT  min(name)'

Comment: beware..the average age and hobby might be from different rows. you shouldn't use this answer.

Comment: I mean just Write name and avg

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Hi , i think this query isnt working, i tried it on some tables i've created here  http://pastebin.com/FcinBwVH

Comment: I think the problem is with the first line "SELECT MIN(avg), min(name)" whice dosen't  sycronaize the age with the right Hobby and just return two seperate attribute that are the min where the one is the min of the ages and the second is the min of the name

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TOP 1 and an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (R.hnum), (R.hname), AVG(age)
FROM Hobby H NATURAL JOIN Person P NATURAL JOIN Hobbies R
GROUP BY (R.hnum), (R.hname)
ORDER BY AVG(age)
```